# Hiding button by "Id" works, but clicking it not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I execute the top portion here automatically.

In this script I can  easily hide "showLine" via `document.getElementById("showLine").style.visibility="hidden";` no problemo,

but `document.getElementById("showLine").click();` will *not* fire no matter what I do...

The button does not press onload..

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

//Autoexecute on pageload
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("showLine").click();
    //document.getElementById("showLine").style.visibility="hidden";
  });
</script>

//script with button "showLine"
<script>
  var lines;
  var randomNumber;
  var lastRandomNumber;
  $(document.body).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://ry3yr.github.io/OSTR/Diarykeepers_Homepage/Daymusic_array.js",
    }).done(function (content) {
      lines = content
        .replace(/\r\n|\r/g, "\n")
        .trim()
        .split("\n");
      lines = content
        .replace(/\r\n|\r/g, "quote")
        .trim()
        .split("quote");
      // ^^ line rmvl ^^^
      if (lines && lines.length) {
        $("#showLine").on("click", function () {
          while (randomNumber === lastRandomNumber) {
            randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * lines.length);
            if (lines.length === 1) {
              break;
            }
          }
          lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;
          $("#trivia").html(lines[randomNumber]);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<button id="showLine">CurrListening</button>
<p id="trivia"></p>
```

So how do I fix this clicking not working ?

PS:
I commented out the button, cause I used the visibility just for test purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing `click()` before the AJAX request resolves.

I would suggest simply triggering a click *after* registering the listener.

```js
$("#showLine")
  .on("click", function () {
    while (randomNumber === lastRandomNumber) {
      randomNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * lines.length);
      if (lines.length === 1) {
        break;
      }
    }
    lastRandomNumber = randomNumber;
    $("#trivia").html(lines[randomNumber]);
  })
  .trigger("click");
```

Comment: Ah ok. So it is a timing issues. That makes sense :). Thanks !

Comment: BTW: Looking at my script above, where you you adviss I place the trigger click event exactly ? I tried various spots, but I might have overseen something ?

Comment: @repeekyraidcero format your code nicely and it won't be as hard to find where to make additions.

Comment: @repeekyraidcero I've cleaned up the formatting in your question so it should be clearer where the `.trigger("click")` goes

Comment: Yes, I was positively surprised after reloading the page :D !

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it after their listener attached! First, you must add a listener and then trigger your click event.